# How publish a full trusted .net 4.5 to medium trust level

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

I developed a website using .NET framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013 on local PC it is working fin,e but on a shared hosting on hostgator it shows error. Hostgator team said your website run full trust level but they provid only medium level trust.

How I change my website from full trust to medium level trust?

Comment: Please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ?

> The following example shows the securityPolicy section of a
>   configuration file that maps the full trust level to a policy file.

In your web.config :

```
<system.web>
  <securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
  </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

Check in your web.config what you have at this section.

Comment: But hostgator team said "Simply making the edits to the web.config file will NOT resolve this issue. The issue is in the base design of the site. From the Development Environment the site must be recompiled for Medium-Trust, Re-published for medium-trust, and then the full site re-uploaded along with all of its dependencies (databases included). This often times can take away some functions that require Full-Trust access but that is not permitted in any case on our Shared Servers."